# C# - RadGrid - How to Call ItemDatabound Event Manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I need to call ItemDataBound event, when RadTextBox text changed. How to achieve this, plz help.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What is your situation ? From where you want to raise the event. Do you want to raise the event or you want to call the method registered with ItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign `RadGrid.DataBind();` method to `RadTextBox.TextChanged` even. So you will get your `ItemDataBound` event fires.

Answer (score 2):

itemdatabound event is fires only at the time of binding radgrid..can not call it on textbox changed event directly..

or you bind your grid on textchanged event then it will call that event